# Client side certificate issue when debugging error 403.16

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm working on a MVC project with a co-worker that requires client-side SSL. The problem is when the project runs on my machine the client side certificate is always rejected with a 403.16 error.

The project works on his machine. The only difference being that i'm on windows 8 and he's on windows 7. The solution also works when published to azure.

I am not sure what configuration step I have missed. Any idea on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit - Adding Certificate setup information**

I have the root CA in the project as a resource. On server start there is a batch file that contains and is run to install it:

```
rem startup script for Windows Azure Cloud Service

date /t >> c:\startup.txt
time /t >> c:\startup.txt

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config /section:access

certutil -addstore root "../App_Data/workflow_ca.cer"


rem must exit

exit /b 0
```

Comment: Can you share how the certificate is configured in your project ?

Comment: Added it to the main question

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS 8.5 - Mutual certificates authentication fails with error 403.16](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232340/iis-8-5-mutual-certificates-authentication-fails-with-error-403-16)